# Unclip в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Допустим у меня есть BorderPane, на который я повесил setClip для анимации появления. После мне нужно убрать этот clip. Как мне это сделать?

```
new GAnimation() {

    Ellipse clip;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
        setAnimationFormula(time -> 1 - Math.pow(2, -16 * time));
        clip = new Ellipse();
        clip.setCenterY(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        setClip(clip);
    }

    @Override
    public void animate(double time) {
        clip.setCenterX(getWidth() / 2);
        double r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(getHeight(), 2) + Math.pow(getWidth() / 2, 2)) * time;
        clip.setRadiusX(r);
        clip.setRadiusY(r);
    }
}.play();
```

GAnimation extends Transition

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, минимальный компилируемый код, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Пример: http://pastebin.com/gRDUE0KD

Comment: Компилируемый - означает, что код должен компилироваться. Минимальный - означает, что в коде не должно быть лишних элементов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты можешь проставить лисенер `setOnFinished()`, в который ты напишешь, что   делать после окончания проигрывания. Будет что-то типо такого

```
    @Override
    public void init() {
        setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
        setAnimationFormula(time -> 1 - Math.pow(2, -16 * time));
        clip = new Ellipse();
        clip.setCenterY(0);
        setOnFinished(event -> setClip(null));
    }
```

Comment: setClip(null) то, что мне и нужно было. теперь у меня public void onEnd() {target.setClip(null);}